# componenetDidUpdate() is not being called

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to delete a `<Table>` data. What I am doing is, selecting the a single row of the `<Table>` and press the `Delete` button (custom made). and the function for Delete is being fired.

The Data is being deleted at the server's end, but the UI is not updated.
here is the code:

```
export default class DeleteUserForms extends Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 1};
    this.data = this.props.selectedValue;
    this.handleDeletedata=this.handleDeletedata.bind(this);
}

handleDeletedata(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Data before delete function call');
    console.log(this.data);
    this.props.dispatch(deleteUser(this.data));
    // this.props.close(event)
}

componentWillUpdate(){
    console.log('COMPONENT WILL UPDATEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE');
    this.props.dispatch(getUserRole())
}

// componentDidMount(){
//     console.log('COMPONENT DID MOUNT');
//     // this.props.close();
// }

componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log('COMPONENT DID UPDATEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE');
    // this.props.close();
}


render(){
    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.handleDeletedata}>
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiThemedrpdown}>
                <div>
                    Do you really want to delete the record for {this.props.selectedValue.name}?
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiThemebtn}>
                <div>
                  <RaisedButton label="Yes" primary={true} type="submit" className="btndiv"  
                    />  
                  <RaisedButton label="No" primary={true} 
                    onClick={this.props.close}  className="btndiv"  />  
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </form> 
      );
```

}
}

Here also I am trying to close a modal after the data has been deleted. but the `componentDidUpdate()` method is not being called.
Please suggest

Comment: Have you got any errors?

Comment: No error in console

Comment: can you post the code of reducer triggered by `deleteUser(this.data)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not refresh, because you assign `date` in the constructor - `date` has always the initial value. The constructor is called only once at the beginning, so `this.data` will always have an initial value `this.props.data`. Component is not refreshing, because nothing has really changed.

try this:

```
this.props.dispatch(deleteUser(this.props.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning `this.data` inside `componentWillReceiveProps` instead, as others have mentioned - the constructor is only called once in the lifecycle of the component.